# when will oracle discontinue the 9i database?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle9i

The Oracle 9i database is starting to look long in the tooth.  When will Oracle discontinue support for it?

Comment: Why don't you check the Oracle website to find out? I don't see anything in your question that is remotely programming related...

Comment: Perhaps more appropo for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: For the ServerFault password see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/server-fault-public-beta-nears/

Comment: Added bonus: folks don't get their knickers in a knot if you ask programming questions there ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](http://www.oracle.com/support/library/brochure/lifetime-support-technology.pdf) is what you're looking for. It doesn't appear that they are ever planning to totally drop support for it.

Comment: Jon, looks like your google-fu is much faster than mine :D

Comment: Actually, I finally found http://www.oracle.com/features/hp/database-9i-support.html which makes it sounds like extended support expired last July.

Answer (score 0):

well ORACLE says Premier Support Ends July 2007 but [Sustaining Support](http://www.oracle.com/support/lifetime-support-policy.html) never ends.  I am not sure about Extended support.  I hear it ends July next year.